# Regex does not work with grep

Tags: ubuntu, regex, grep

Why does this match

```
.*\/.+\/wp-admin.*404
[03/Sep/2021:18:58:29 +0200] "GET /up/wp-admin/install.php HTTP/1.1" 404 6197
```

[regexr.com](https://regexr.com/650gr)

But in grep it does not?

```
sudo grep -rh ".*\/.+\/wp-admin.*404" /var/log/apache2/ | wc -l
0
```

I know the line exists in that folder. If I replace + by * it works.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU grep, you have to backslash-escape the '+' character. Can you please try this `grep -rh ".*\/.\+\/wp-admin.*404" /var/log/apache2/ | wc -l`